# how jsp-android web service work without hosting for testing

Tags: android, mysql, web-services, jsp

i want to do a academic web-android project that named tour-trips planer. but web service part is not working in it. i want MySQL database to access my android app. how to work it without hosting? and i'm totally a beginner..

Answer (score 0):

you need to your android application and web service in the same network 
you can do this using one of these methods

- using app to share network connectify
- see this [How can I access my localhost from my Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device)
- and this [How can I access my localhost from my Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device/16510143#16510143)

i hope this helps you